# ¿Cómo puedo comparar los datos de un vector en Java?

Tags: java, array

mi problema es el siguiente: Resulta que tengo un vector de tipo int, que tiene 20 datos, dentro de dicho vector existen datos repetidos. Lo que intento hacer es comparar los elementos de dicho vector con el fin de reconocer cuando un dato se repite, por ejemplo si en la posición 1 tengo un 23 y en la posición 7 aparece nuevamente, despliega un mensaje que dice que hay una valor repetido en la posición (i). El código que formule es el siguiente, sin embargo no logro hacer dicha acción, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias a todos.

```
int v[] = new int {5,23,12,67,88,43,12,78,91,112,114,67,81,223,456,789,400,340, 86,91};
for(int i =0; i<v.lenght(); i++){
  for(int j=0; j<v.lenght(); j++){
     if(i!= j && v[i]==v[j]){
        System.out.println("Valor repetido en la posición: " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que yo haría sería lo siguiente, tengo que comparar el primer valor del arreglo(dejar el indice quieto ahi para i) con los siguientes restantes valores del arreglo o sea que j tiene que iniciar en "int j=i+1 , una vez que termine j de recorrer todos los restantes valores del arreglo empezando desde "i+1" , entonces i pasasaria a valer 1 y j pasaría a valer 2 y asi evito poner en el if el "i!=j" , entonces:

```
....
for(int j=i+1 ; j<v.length() ; j++){
if(v[i]==v[j]){
System.out.println("Valor repetido en la posicion: " + j);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int v[] = {5,23,12,67,88,43,12,78,91,112,114,67,81,223,456,789,400,340, 86,91};
 for(int i =0; i< v.length; i++)
 {
    for(int j=0; j<v.length; j++)
   {
        if(i!= j && v[i]==v[j]){
            System.out.println("Valor repetido en la posición: " + i);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: por qué este código es la respuesta a la pregunta? procura siempre que tu respuesta sea útil a todos los que lleguen a consultarla

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa sería utilizar un HashMap.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
...
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int [] v = {5,23,12,67,88,43,12,78,91,112,114,67,81,223,456,789,400,340, 86,91};
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(v[i])) {
            System.out.println("Valor repetido en la posición: " + map.get(v[i]));
        } else {
            map.put(v[i], i);
        }
    }
...
```